# Scipy: Continuous Uniform Distribution's CDF

Tags: uniform-distribution, scipy

### Question

**How can we solve the problem below with Scipy?**

**Background:** I am preparing statictics notes in Jupyter Notebooks and trying to apply appropriate Scipy functions to some real cases.

**Problem:** I found a good case in [lumenlerning.com](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/the-uniform-distribution/) and I can solve the problem with the formulas. Nevertheless, I cannot find a function in Scipy to solve this problem.

**Case:** A company finds out that the amount of time a repairman needs to fix a furnace is uniformly distributed between 1.5 and 4 hours. What is the probability that a randomly selected furnace repair requires more than 2 hours?

```
# PDF function, f(x)
1/(4-1.5) = 0.4 

# probability of occurrence between 2 and 4: 
(4-2) = 2

# answer
0.4 * 2 = 0.8
```

**Snapshot of the solution:**
[image]

---

### Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to find the pdf for this problem, because a simple answer comes directly from the definition of a uniform distribution: namely, the chance of an event is its length as a proportion of the total length of the domain.  Thus, all you need do is write a program to compute the length of the interval $[x, 4]$ as a fraction of the length of the interval $[1.5, 4].$ That requires only a few basic checks (to see whether $x\in[1.5,4]$), two subtractions, and a division.

Answer (score 1):

*Software questions are in general off-topic on this site, but there seems to be a probability problem behind your question, so let me answer it.*

As about Scipy, it has [nice documentation for the probability distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/continuous.html) and you are looking for the [uniform distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html#scipy.stats.uniform). It has rather unorthodox parameters, because instead of lower and upper bounds, it uses `loc` for lower bound and `scale` where the upper bound is `loc + scale`.

You geometric solution is correct, but would be hard to translate to other distributions. More generic solution would be noticing that $\Pr(l < X < u) = \Pr(X < u) - \Pr(X < l) = \int_l^u f(x) \,dx$, so you can use the cumulative distribution functions. This takes the area till $u$ and subtracts from it the left tail ending at $l$.

```py
>>> from scipy.stats import uniform
>>> dist = uniform(loc=1.5, scale=2.5)
>>> dist.pdf(2)
0.4
>>> dist.cdf(4) - dist.cdf(2)
0.8
```

Comment: Extremely well described. Many thanks for your efforts! I have used sf: survival function to get the result. Still confused about scale especially.

Comment: OK. Got that;
scale = upper bound  - lower bound (loc)
